# How to Project an Element in an Array of Objects in mongoDB for All Documents from a Collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have an array of objects in my company collection holding grouped values as follows:

```
"groups" : [
        {
            "id" : "d278c44333",
            "name" : "group 1"
        }
    ],
```

so in mongoDB it would be `company > groups > 0 > id or name`

I want to project all of the documents that have the groups array of objects and retrieve the name.

How can I do that?

Here is what i tried:

```
db.getCollection("Company").aggregate([
            
    {
        $match: { 
            "companyID": "323452343",

        }
    },

    {
        $project: { 
            //this only projects groupName with an array with 0 elements inside.
            groupName: "$groups.0.name"

         }
        
    }

])
```

EDIT:

expected result:

[image]

Comment: Do you want to get all documents that have '$groups.0.name' regardless of the value?

Comment: @nimrodserok yes, however it will always have a value since in my collection every document has this groups array of objects with an id and a name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the specific case of the first item use:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      groupName: {
        $first: "$groups.name"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iyKWahyjctu)

For mongodb version older than 4.2 use:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      groupName: {
        $arrayElemAt: ["$groups.name", 0]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: but i want all the groups elements name not only one element name, how would i achieve that? the case in the question was just an example.

Comment: Please provide a valid document with few items in the array, and the expected result of it, and I'll updated the answer

Comment: I did provide a document with items in the array, i think you misunderstood what i want to achieve. every document in my collection has this groups array and has only and id and a name. Now, i want to project all of my collections documents (only with some fields that i need) along with the groups name that i am unable to project

Comment: In order to understand, please provide the requested result of this query

Comment: It would just be like this. (please refer to the edited question)

Comment: I tried your solution, doesn't work. it gives me an error reading `"(InvalidPipelineOperator): 'Unrecognized expression '$first''"` in Intellishell in studio 3t

Comment: What is your mongodb version?

Comment: Thank you, your second answer is what i finally found that works. but what if i wanted to project all of the elements in the array of objects, not just the first one?

Comment: Then use [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OPQ7lQodKoo)

Comment: this will return an array with the names inside, i want to project all the names that are inside the array

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the right way to query and project the nested array of object as follows:

I had to use `$arrayElemAt` as such:

```
db.getCollection("Comapny").aggregate([
            
    {
        $match: { 
            "companyID": "123456789",
              
               
        }
    },
    
    {
        $sort: { _updated_at: -1 }
    },
        
    {
        $project: { 
            _id: "$_id",
           
            groups: {$arrayElemAt: [ "$groups.name", 0 ] },               

         }
        
    }

])
```